# How to interrupt ForkJoinTasks in ForkJoinPool?

Tags: java, android, interrupt, forkjoinpool

For example, there is a `LinkedList <ForkJoinTask>` of [`ForkJoinTasks`](https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-for-api-level-23/blob/master/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.java). Then I expect the results:

First way:

```
for (ForkJoinTask task: subTasks) {
    task.join ();  // how interrupt?
}
```

Second way:

```
for (ForkJoinTask task: subTasks) {
    try {
       task.get ();  // how interrupt, InterruptedException not thrown, because Thread.currentThread() instanceof ForkJoinWorkerThread ?
    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException ignored) {}
}
```

In the second case, the command [`task.get()`](https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-for-api-level-23/blob/master/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.java#L955) leads to the command [`doJoin()`](https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-for-api-level-23/blob/master/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.java#L345) and the exception is not thrown.

How do I interrupt these expectations: task.join or task.get.

Comment: Could you explain what do you want to achieve ? Do you want to cancel task if it takes too long or on some other condition ?

Comment: I already explained.  > some other condition